# Jira automation - mention user in comment

Tags: automation, jira

I am doing some automations in Jira.

I am adding comments like this to cards
"User name approved the MTP on 2023-07-20"

However, the user name is being entered as a text. I want it to be added as a @ mention of the user in jira.
I found info here : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Mention-users-in-automation-comment/qaq-p/1515480
to use something like this :
[~accountid:{{issue.assignee.accountId}}]
but it is not working.

This is what i put as the comment in the Automation rule

```
Test comment by {{initiator.displayName}} on {{now}}
email : {{initiator.emailAddress}}

AccountId : [~accountid:{{initiator.accountId}}]
```

and this is the comment appearing in the card

```
Test comment by User name on 2023-07-25T18:40:28.6-0500 email :
user.name@company.com AccountId : [~accountid:JIRAUSER116036]
```

Does anyone know how can i tag/mention a user in a comment in an automated rule ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
Test comment by {{initiator.displayName}} on {{now}}
email : {{initiator.emailAddress}}

AccountId : [~{{initiator}}]
```

It works for me.